# How to assign data-bind value to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

New to asp.net

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <p>Showing results for FU <span data-bind="text: selectedFu() ? selectedFu().fuId : ''" /></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        @{
            var sfuId = "Bar";
        }

        @if (sfuId == "Bar") {
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="warn">
                        <span data-bind="text: barDisclaimer"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

Works but how do I assign var sfuId = selectedFu() ? selectedFu().fuId.I have tried var sfuId = ", data-bind="if:, and ko.observable() but can't seem to get anything to work.

Thank You tkestowicz. knockoutjs.com is a great site. I will read through and post if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for data-bind="visible
Tkestowicz's suggested site was very helpful.

```
        <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <p>Showing results for FU <span data-bind="text: selectedFu() ? selectedPpo().fuId : ''" /></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body form-horizontal" data-bind="visible: selectedFu() ? selectedFu().fuId : false">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="warn">
                <span data-bind="text: barDisclaimer"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The title (or the code) is wrong. This:

```
    @{
        var sfuId = "Bar";
    }
```

Is not JavaScript, it is C# code written with Razor syntax. Looking at this example it seems like you want to access JavaScript object under C#. It is not possible because C# code is compiled before JavaScript executes. You can do only the opposite - pass C# value to JS.

I think that you misunderstood the purpose of Razor. It's a server side template engine which means that all the code executes before being rendered in the browser. On the other hand Knockout is a JavaScript (client side) library.

Use KO template (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) instead of Razor to make it working.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about asp or c# but in javascript this is how i do it

```
my_node = document.querySelector("some_node");

// normal/safe method
my_node.getAttribute("data-task");
my_node.setAttribute("data-task", "new_value");

// be modern
my_node.dataset.task;
my_node.dataset.task = "new_value";
```